# How to provide chrome profile in selenium grid nodeconfig

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm starting my Selenium node with the profile setting provided in nodeConfig.json, but Chrome driver still doesn't use it.

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Selenium_server\chromedriver.exe -jar C:\Selenium_server\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json

nodeConfig.json:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
 {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "maxInstances": 5,
  "version": "username",
  "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
  "profile-directory": "Profile 2"
  "user-data-dir": "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
 }
],
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"maxSession": 5,
"port": -1,
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"hub": "<hub ip>",
"nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
"nodePolling": 5000,
"role": "node",
"unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
"downPollingLimit": 2,
"debug": false,
"servlets" : [],
"withoutServlets": [],
"custom": {}
}
```